# Error al importar componente de VUE en JEST

Tags: vue.js, webpack, test, jest

Cuando intento importar un componente a mi fichero de test, me da un error:

> FAIL  src/specs/test.spec.js
> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Cannot find module '@/components/Login.vue' from 'src/specs/test.spec.js'
>
> > 1 | import Login from '@/components/Login.vue'
> ```

La configuración de los archivos son:

**jest.config.js**

```
// // jest.config.js
 const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
 module.exports = {
//   // ...
   roots: ["<rootDir>/src/"],

   moduleNameMapper: {
     "@app/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
     "@lib/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/lib/$1",
   },
   "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "json", "vue" ],
   transform: {
     "^[^.]+.vue$": "vue-jest",
     "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
   },
   collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
   
 };
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env',];
  const plugins = ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

He leído que se puede utilizar webpack para poder solucionarlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el archivo esta en `src/components/Login.vue` y tu test está en `src/specs/test.spec.js` debes usar una ruta relativa

```
import Login from '../components/Login.vue'
```

o la ruta con alias @app (equivalente a /src)

```
import Login from '@app/components/Login.vue'
```

(`@` por si solo generalmente hace referencia a otra carpeta, node_modules)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, en sí tu respuesta responde a la pregunta. Ahora me sale el siguiente error: Error:                                                                        
  Webpack Compilation Error
./src/components/Login.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Comment: Puede que necesites instalar en el proyecto `vue-loader` y `vue-template-compiler`
 `npm install -D vue-loader vue-template-compiler` y revisar si esta configurado Vue en webpack. Pareciera que no reconoce archivos .vue para compilar

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta me ha servido